# Axios response is not defined in .then method

Tags: javascript, axios

I cannot figure out what is going on here.  It appears to be some sort of timing/async issue.  I have an axios POST which has a chained .then that runs another function with an axios GET request.  The GET request has a chained .then which builds an object called itemInformation and returns it.  The first .then on the POST has a second .then chained which needs to process the itemInformation object.

Sorry if all that was confusing, hopefully the code will make more sense of it.  I am console logging the object in both places and my console logs are appearing backwards from what I would expect them.  So that is why I'm thinking it may be some sort of async or timing issue here.

Code: (addToCartVue is called first)

```
addToCartVue(itemData) {
  let vm = this;

  vm.buildDataString(itemData); // just a simple function that creates the dataString, dataObject and quantity vars; no need to show this whole function

  return axios.post(POST_ENDPOINT, {
      data: vm.dataString
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    }).then(response => {
    vm.updateCartInfo(vm.dataObject, itemData.addToCartParameters.itemId, vm.selectedStoreId, vm.quantity);
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("info2: ", response);
    if (itemData.addToCartParameters.showLB) {
      vm.emitGlobalEvent('addToCart::open', response);
      return (response);
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
},
updateCartInfo(dataObject, itemId, selectedStore, quantity) {
  return axios.get(GET_ENDPOINT, {
    params: dataObject,
  }).then(response => {

    let addedItem = null;
    let basketInfo = null;
    let productQuantity = null;
    try {
      cartDropDown.populateCartDropDown(response.data);

      addedItem = response.data.addedItem;
      basketInfo = response.data.basketInfo;

      productQuantity = quantity;
      if (addedItem.quantity > -1) {
        productQuantity = addedItem.quantity;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    const itemInformation = {
      "itemId": itemId,
      "selectedStore": selectedStore,
      "addedItem": addedItem,
      "basketInfo": basketInfo,
      "displayValues": null,
      "quantity": productQuantity,
      "isCustomProduct": false
    };

    console.log("info1: ", itemInformation);

    return itemInformation;
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

And here is what I see in my console output:
[image]

Every Axios tutorial I find online shows how to do the basic `axios.get(url).then(get response).catch(catch error)`  I'm not finding any examples on more complicated use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` value does not go through multiple chain links. You had this code:

```js
// ... 
}).then(response => {
    vm.updateCartInfo(vm.dataObject, itemData.addToCartParameters.itemId, vm.selectedStoreId, vm.quantity);
}).then(response => {
    console.log("info2: ", response);
    if (itemData.addToCartParameters.showLB) {
        vm.emitGlobalEvent('addToCart::open', response);
        return (response);
    }
}) // ...
```

You have two `then` chain links. In the first one, `response` is defined, as you can see in your console log. **You need to return it** so that it gets passed to the second link. If the `then` function has no `return` value, then the next promise chain `then` will receive `undefined`, as you also see.

As for the order of your `console` logs, Promises always resolve async. Therefore,  since in `updateCartInfo` you're doing `axios.get(GET_ENDPOINT, ...).then( ... console.log() ... )`, it's asynchronously waiting on `axios.get`. During this time, the other `then` ("info2") gets executed. It doesn't wait on the `updateCartInfo` promise since you didn't return it.